# How to diagnose hanging/freezing?

Tags: windows, freeze, crash, overclocking

I have gathered a lot of information already on many different issues-- mainly through websites like these where people seek answers regarding troubleshooting with computers/components. So I figured I'd give it a shot and ask my own question.

I've been trying to figure out for the longest time how to diagnose minor hanging or short periods of time that my computer will freeze (10-30 seconds). I have been able to figure out a Crash/BSOD for the most part when that has happened in the past, but the freezing/hanging issue has been bugging me for so long. There has to be a way or some type of program(s) that can help to debug why this keeps happening and the root of the cause. Any help is greatly appreciated, let me know what information is needed from me and I will provide it for you.

Minor Specs:

- Windows 7 - 64 Bit
- EVGA NVidia GeForce GTX 660 TI 2GB
- AMD-FX 8350
- Asus M5A97 r2.0 (Motherboard)
- 24 GB Corsair Vegeance RAM PC3-12800
- Hard Drive 1: Seagate 1 TB
- Hard Drive 2: WD 500 GB

Comment: press the CAPS LOCK key during the hang and look if the light on your keyboard toggles or not. If it toggles, you have a software issue, if not the hardware causes the freeze.

Answer (score 0):

You should run Perfmon [here one example how to set it up](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/securitytools/archive/2009/11/04/how-to-use-perfmon-in-windows-7.aspx) 
 After the fact review what is happening with CPU, RAM, Disk IO and etc.